# Printing a 2-D array diagonally

Tags: performance, beginner, c, array

The case scenario:

A  2-D array is given:

```
1  3  6  10 15
2  5  9  14 19 
4  8  13 18 22
7  12 17 21 24
11 16 20 23 25
```

and its size `N` is given as 5.

The program should output it as

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

The code I wrote for this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int N = 5;
    int pixel_array[5][5] = {
        {1, 3, 6, 10, 15}, {2, 5, 9, 14, 19}, {4, 8, 13, 18, 22}, {7, 12, 17, 21, 24}, {11, 16, 20, 23, 25}

    };

    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
    {
        if (row < N - 1)
        {
            for (int temp_row = row, col = 0; temp_row >= 0; temp_row--, col++)
                printf("%d ", pixel_array[temp_row][col]);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
                for (int temp_col = col, temp_row = N - 1; temp_col < N; temp_col++, temp_row--)
                    printf("%d ", pixel_array[temp_row][temp_col]);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works fine and outputs the required result.

Some specific questions:

Since there are many `for` loops here -

- how can I decrease code length?
- how can I improve the efficiency of this program?
- Any other programming practices to be implemented?

Any advice would help.

Comment: Please remove the part with "ascending order". It Is irelevant And confusing because it only happens to produce ascending order in the specific case of input you provided (And some others but not for all inputs). The diagonal traversal Is the point here if i get it right...

Answer (score 4):

> How can I decrease code length?

You could split your big `for` loop into `2` smaller ones. The first one would print all diagonals up to the main one, and the other one the remaining ones.

For instance, let's say there's a matrix like:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Then, your first loop would print `1 4 2 7 5 3` and the second one `8 6 9`. The code would look conciser and more readable too:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        printf("%d ", pixel_array[i - j][j]);
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < N - 1; j++) {
    for (int i = N - 1; i > j; i--) {
        printf("%d ", pixel_array[i][N - i + j]);
    }
}
```

> How can I improve the efficiency of this program?

I don't think it's possible to make it more efficient than O(n²) as you have to go through all matrix elements to print them diagonally. So, the suggested solution is efficient enough.

> Any other programming practices to be implemented

Rather than using an `int` type for defining a size of your array, you could use `uint32_t` (or `uint16_t` or `uint64_t` - it depends on your requirements). Your size cannot be negative, anyways. So, change `int N = 5;` to `const uint32_t N = 5`.

Rename your `array` to `squareMatrix` because you're actually dealing with square matrices in your app.

Also, create a method out of your algorithm block - but I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: `size_t` is the usual recommended type for object counts...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `main()` must return an `int`:

```
int main(void)
```

We can make the array initialization easier to read with judicious use of whitespace:

```
static const int N = 5;
const int pixel_array[5][5] =
    {
     {1,  3,  6,  10, 15},
     {2,  5,  9,  14, 19},
     {4,  8,  13, 18, 22},
     {7,  12, 17, 21, 24},
     {11, 16, 20, 23, 25}
    };
```

Instead of the `if`/`else` inside the loop, notice that the `else` is only taken on the last iteration, and move that out:

> ```
> for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
> {
>     if (row < N - 1)
>     {
>         for (int temp_row = row, col = 0; temp_row >= 0; temp_row--, col++)
>             printf("%d ", pixel_array[temp_row][col]);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
>             for (int temp_col = col, temp_row = N - 1; temp_col < N; temp_col++, temp_row--)
>                 printf("%d ", pixel_array[temp_row][temp_col]);
>     }
> }
> ```

becomes

```
for (int row = 0;  row < N - 1;  row++)
{
    for (int temp_row = row, col = 0; temp_row >= 0; temp_row--, col++)
        printf("%d ", pixel_array[temp_row][col]);
}

/* row == N - 1 */
for (int col = 0;  col < N;  col++)
    for (int temp_col = col, temp_row = N - 1; temp_col < N; temp_col++, temp_row--)
        printf("%d ", pixel_array[temp_row][temp_col]);
```

We can move the printing of the main diagonal to the first loop, so that its condition is `row < N` and remove it from the second loop by starting `col` at `1`.  Also observe that `temp_row` and `temp_col` can always be derived from `row` and `column`:

```
for (int row = 0;  row < N;  ++row) {
    for (int col = 0;  col <= row;  ++col) {
        printf("%d ", pixel_array[row-col][col]);
    }
}

for (int col = 1;  col < N;  ++col) {
    for (int row = N - 1;  row >= col;  --row) {
        printf("%d ", pixel_array[row][col+N-1-row]);
    }
}
```